# I have a SeekBar. When the user is dragging the 'thumb', a Popup appears above the thumb below Android 4.0

Tags: android

I have a SeekBar in my application, and I want it to behave so that when the user is dragging the 'thumb', a Popup appears above the thumb (and follows it as the thumb is dragged), and the Popup displays the corresponding positon of the SeekBar (or any other text that position may represent).

I have done it in Android 4.0+ by using the `setX()` method, but it's not supporting Android 2.3 and below.

So, how it is possible?
Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Hi shripal just use like this in `onProgressChange` Method of `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
int x = seekBar1.getThumb().getBounds().left;   
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMarginStart(x);
textView1.setLayoutParams(params);
textView1.setText("x="+x);
```

It will set margine from left as thumb inceass.